# In my ArrayList of Arraylists, why are the all the actions on individual elements effecting all other indexes?

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist, javafx

I have nested Arraylists that compose a book:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<PageContents>> book = new ArrayList<>(); //A list of lists
private ArrayList<PageContents> page = new ArrayList<>(); //A List of objects

book.add(page); //Add new(first) page in book.
PageContents pageContents = new PageContents(); //Create a new line
pagecontents.setLine("This is a line on the page"); //Edit the line
book.get(0).add(pagecontents); //Add the new (first) line to the first page of the book.
```

So, in practice, `book.get(0).get(0).getLine();` would return the first line of of the first page of the book.

**The Problem**

I initially thought everything was working fine, since the initial part of my development involved getting a single page right, then I would worry about multiple pages.  Then, when I appended a `page`list to the `book` ArrayList with `book.new(page);` I found out that it was exactly the same as the `page` at `book.get(0)`.
So the value of `book.get(0).get(0)` was exactly the same as `book.get(1).get(0)`,  OR `book.get(0).get(20)`was exactly the same as `book.get(1).get(20)`.

I then thought "No big deal,it must be copying the data from `book.get(0)`.  I'll just clear the new `page` arraylist with `book.get(1).clear();` right after I create it."  But that cleared book.get(0) too.  Then I changed the data at `book.get(1).get(9);`, and it also changed `book.get(0).get(9);` to the same value.

Now I don't know what is going on.  I thought it might have something to do with a few lines where I sync the 'book' data with a different class, thinking perhaps is was copying the pointers so every`page' pointed to the same data, but after a but of testing I eliminated that as the culprit. (I just deleted those methods)

Is my use of ArrayLists just flawed in my implementation?
So far the ArrayList structure has been perfect for my purposes (until I needed a new `page`, that is).  I just need each new `page` arraylist to be blank and unique what added to the `book` list.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks Guys!

**More Complete Example:**

*Code*

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<PageContents>> book = new ArrayList<>(); //A list of lists
private ArrayList<PageContents> page = new ArrayList<>(); //A List of objects

book.add(page); //Add new(first) page in book.
PageContents pageContents1 = new PageContents(); //Create a new line
pagecontents1.setLine("This is Line 1 on Page 1"); //Edit the line
book.get(0).add(pagecontents1); //Add the new (first) line to the first page of the book.

System.out.println("Page1 size: " + book.get(0).size() + "pages");
System.out.println("Page1: " + book.get(0).get(0).getLine());

System.out.println("Page2 size: " + book.get(1).size() + "pages");

if(book.get(1).isEmpty())  //Should book.get(1) should be empty
{
    System.out.println("Page2: EMPTY");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Page2: " + book.get(1).get(0).getLine());
}
```

*Output* (Incorrect)

```
Page1 size: 1
Page1: This is Line 1 on Page 1 
Page2 size: 1
Page2: This is Line 1 on Page 1
```

*Output* (What it should be if the code worked as intended)

```
Page1 size: 1
Page1: This is Line 1 on Page 1 
Page2 size: 0
Page2: EMPTY
```

*If I ADD This New Code* (To give Page 2 contents)

```
PageContents pageContents2 = new PageContents(); //Create a new line
pagecontents2.setLine("This is Line 1 on Page 2"); //Edit the line
book.get(0).add(pagecontents1); //Add the new (first) line to the second page of the book.

System.out.println("Page1 size: " + book.get(0).size() + "pages");
System.out.println("Page1: " + book.get(0).get(1).getLine());
System.out.println("Page2 size: " + book.get(1).size() + "pages");
System.out.println("Page2: " + book.get(1).get(1).getLine());
```

*Output* (Incorrect, both pages making the same changes)

```
Page1 size: 2
Page1: This is Line 1 on Page 1 
Page2 size: 2
Page2: This is Line 1 on Page 1
Page1 size: 2
Page1: This is Line 1 on Page 2 
Page2 size: 2
Page2: This is Line 1 on Page 2
```

Since I added a new line, both `page`lists have 2 lines.  Each should only have one line with different values.

Comment: First thing, you're equal sign needs to be in the quotations: `= "pages"` should be `+ " = pages"`. Either that or change the `=` to `+` so that you just have `+ "pages"`

Comment: Yeah, simple copy/paste mistake.  I fixed it.  Meant to put a `+` to concatenate.

Comment: Make sure you're setting `page` to a new ArrayList before you start creating the second page; otherwise you'll just add the same page to `book` twice, and just modify it on the second iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class PageContents
{
    String Line;

    public String getLine()
    {
        return Line;
    }

    public void setLine(String line)
    {
        Line = line;
    }

}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<PageContents>> book = new ArrayList<>(); 
        ArrayList<PageContents> page1 = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add new(first) page in book.
        PageContents pageContents1 = new PageContents();
        pageContents1.setLine("This is Line 1 on Page 1"); 
        page1.add(pageContents1); 
        book.add(page1);

        ArrayList<PageContents> page2 = new ArrayList<>();
        PageContents pageContents2 = new PageContents();
        pageContents2.setLine("This is Line 1 on Page 2");
        page2.add(pageContents2);
        book.add(page2);

        System.out.println("Page1 size: " + book.get(0).size() + "pages");
        System.out.println("Page1: " + book.get(0).get(0).getLine());

        System.out.println("Page2 size: " + book.get(1).size() + "pages");

        if (book.get(1).isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Page2: EMPTY");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Page2: " + book.get(1).get(0).getLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This holds the answer.  As a few people have suggested, I needed to make a new `page` list, then add it to the `book` list.  In Nani'2015's answer, it's `ArrayList<PageContents> page2 = new ArrayList<>();`   I actually thought I was doing that, but my actual program that I tried to pull this issue from is more dynamic and I was actually trying to add the first `page` created for page 1.  In my actual program new `page`s are created in a method call, so I just made the `newPage` list there and added it to the `book` list.  Now every `newPage` added to `book` is a new instance. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your demo program is correct?

I tried the code below and got an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. Your code must be doing something more than what you have posted...

```
Exception in thread "main" Page1 size: 1pages
Page1: This is Line 1 on Page 1
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at BookThingy.main(BookThingy.java:17)
```

Code...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookThingy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<PageContents>> book = new ArrayList<>(); //A list of lists
        ArrayList<PageContents> page = new ArrayList<>(); //A List of objects

        book.add(page); //Add new(first) page in book.
        PageContents pageContents1 = new PageContents(); //Create a new line
        pageContents1.setLine("This is Line 1 on Page 1"); //Edit the line
        book.get(0).add(pageContents1); //Add the new (first) line to the first page of the book.

        System.out.println("Page1 size: " + book.get(0).size() + "pages");
        System.out.println("Page1: " + book.get(0).get(0).getLine());

        System.out.println("Page2 size: " + book.get(1).size() + "pages");

        if(book.get(1).isEmpty())  //Should book.get(1) should be empty
        {
            System.out.println("Page2: EMPTY");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Page2: " + book.get(1).get(0).getLine());
        }
    }

    public static class PageContents {
        private String line;

        public String getLine() {
            return line;
        }

        public void setLine(String line) {
            this.line = line;
        }
    }
}
```

Post your complete code (if possible) or check that other methods are not modifying your lists and then I'll modify this answer...

Comment: Sorry, can't post the whole thing.  It's got about 1800 lines.  I'm pulling the code out of a larger program to isolate the issue.  I should have ran the example I posted before posting.  Sorry about that.   I'll try to clean it up.  Problem is, If the above concept is sound, then I screwed something else up somewhere along the line.  Everything was great until I needed a new blank list added to the book list.